# Coding monitor python

Tags: python, monitor

I am trying to implement a monitor for website. I would like to receive an email everytimes an item which is sold out became aviable. (Or if a new item is added)

When I run this code the output is: Process finished with exit code 0.

I'm a beginner with Python, is there something wrong? How do I run this code like 24/24? Do I receive the email? (Obviously there are my info in myaddress, password etc).

It looks like nothing happened ...

```py
#import urllib2
import smtplib
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

import hashlib
import random
import time


# url to be scraped
url = "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products/blue-af1-mca#"

# time between checks in seconds
sleeptime = 60


def getHash():
    # random integer to select user agent
    randomint = random.randint(0, 7)

    # User_Agents
    # This helps skirt a bit around servers that detect repeaded requests from the same machine.
    # This will not prevent your IP from getting banned but will help a bit by pretending to be different browsers
    # and operating systems.
    user_agents = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
        'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
        'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19'
    ]

    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', user_agents[randomint])]
    response = opener.open(url)
    the_page = response.read()

    return hashlib.sha224(the_page).hexdigest()


current_hash = getHash()  # Get the current hash, which is what the website is now

while 1:  # Run forever
    if getHash() == current_hash:  # If nothing has changed
        print
        "Not Changed"
    else:  # If something has changed
        email = 'myaddress@gmail.com'  # Your email
        password = 'password'  # Your email account password
        send_to_email = 'sentoaddreess@gmail.com'  # Who you are sending the message to
        message = 'This is my message'  # The message in the email

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  # Connect to the server
        server.starttls()  # Use TLS
        server.login(email, password)  # Login to the email server
        server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, message)  # Send the email
        server.quit()  # Logout of the email server
        break
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

Comment: Please fix your code snippet indentation. This is Python so broken indentation = syntax error (and if the runtime can't make sense of your code, we can't either).

Comment: Also - even with indentation fixed - this _can not_ be the code that gives you "Process finished with exit code 0" - `return` isn't allowed outside a function. So please post a proper [mcve] (and explain how you run this script).

Comment: you don't understand : if the indentation is broken __we__ cannot tell what's wrong with your code, because it doesn't make any sense. And this is not the only missing information, so if you hope to get any serious help please edit your question according to my previous comments.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Ok thx - a couple last questions though: how do you run this code, and why the google-chrome tag ?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm, and I'm gonna delete Chrome, it's useless im sorry

Comment: Have you tried running your script directly from the command line ? (nb: complex IDEs like PyCharm actually make life harder for beginner by hiding a lot of things, messing with sys.path and current working directory etc etc etc. Better to learn with a minimal environment (any basic code editor and the command line) and only switch to an IDE when you have enough experience to choose, configure and understand your IDE.)

Answer (score 0):

> When I run this code the output is: Process finished with exit code 0.

Well, this usually means that the script has been executed without error, but since you're running it from PyCharm I can't say much more. Run the script from the command line instead and you'll find out what happens.

> I'm a beginner with Python, is there something wrong?

Well, your code doesn't have any obvious error that would prevent it from running, but the way it's written doesn't help with debugging (more on this later). And it probably has a logical error (idem).

Here's a slightly revised (but functionnally equivalent) version:

```
import smtplib
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

import hashlib
import random
import time

# mail config
smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_port = 587
smtp_login = 'myaddress@gmail.com'  # Your email
smtp_password = 'password'  # Your email account password
recipient_email = 'sentoaddreess@gmail.com'  # Who you are sending the message to

# url to be scraped
url = "https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/products/blue-af1-mca#"

# time between checks in seconds
sleeptime = 60

user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
    'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19'
]

def get_random_agent():
    return random.choice(user_agents)

def get_page(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', get_random_agent())]
    response = opener.open(url)
    content = response.read()
    response.close()
    return content

def get_hash(url):
    page = get_page(url)
    return hashlib.sha224(page).hexdigest()

def sendmail(message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smpt_port)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(smtp_login, smtp_password)
    server.sendmail(smtp_login, recipient_email, message)
    server.quit()

def main():
    current_hash = get_hash(url)
    while True:  # Run forever => well, nope... cf below

        time.sleep(sleeptime)

        if get_hash(url) = current_hash: 
            print("Not Changed")
            continue

        print("changed, sending mail")
        sendmail("has changed")
        break # really ??? This means that you exit the loop here !

# this allow to use the script as either a script (python yourscript.py) or module
# so you can import it in a Python shell and test functions in isolation
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can noticed, I splitted the logic into small functions, and wrapped the main loop in a `main()` function, which is only executed if the file is used as a script (`> python yourfile.py` on the command line). This allow you to import the script in a python shell as module (without triggering the main function) and test functions in isolation, ie:

```
bruno@blookup-MS-7982:~/Work/playground$ python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Jul  9 2019, 16:51:35) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import somail
>>> somail.get_hash(somail.url)
'adc545b6e40da7b9a4c1319a933b7921e21f7877a03080ec720c71c9'
>>>
```

> How do I run this code like 24/24?

Well, first you may want to think twice about the `break` statement in your `while` loop. If you expect your code to "run forever", you don't want to exit the loop, do you ?-)

Once this is fixed, your loop will indeed "run forever" - or, more exactly, until something fails for whatever reason (site down, network error, smtp error etc), since you have exactly zero error handling - but that's actually better than badly done error handling since at least you'll have the error message and the full traceback to tell you what went wrong, so you know which exceptions you have to handle and where to handle them.

Now it still requires that you launch your program (from the commandline or whatever) *and let the process run* - if you kill your terminal this will kill the script too.

Now there are ways to "detach" a process from the shell but this is system specific (on linux/unices those are named "daemons", on Windows they are named "services" IIRC), and it's a full question in itself actually.

> Do I receive the email? (Obviously there are my info in myaddress, password etc).

Err... How can WE know if YOU received the email ?-)

This being said, all we can really know is that [if the script executed without error](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail), at least the SMTP server accepted the mail. What happens to the message then, no one can know (until, possibly, someone finds it in his mailbox).

> It looks like nothing happened ...

Your original code only mentions when nothing changed. It doesn't give any feedback when a change is detected. The first simple easy way to trace code execution is to spice your code with `print` statements so you can see in direct what it's doing (production code would use proper logging). The second thing to do to test your code is what I did: slit it into small, focused function (each doing one single thing), and test your functions from the python shell.

The next step (pun intended) is to run your code under a step debugger, but that's also too wide a topic. But this is still a required skill...